# How to use Egit with ssh

Tags: eclipse, git, egit

I have always used gitHub as my repository but now I decided to store my source code into my local server (Ubuntu 14.04).

I use Eclipse as IDE and to make it working with git I installed Egit plugin.
My objective is to have a centralised repository in my local server at 10.3.16.1 and use my desktop pc and my macbook to push and fetch data from it.

My existing maven spring web based application sits at the moment on my laptop (eclipse)

I created a local git repo and then I added and committed all files. (so far so good)

Afterwards, I created a new remote as follow

[image]

I then pushed the master branch to the server but despite it says that the process has been successful I cannot clone the entire source code from my pc but only metadata like commits etc but not source files

[image]

Any thoughts on this?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to solve this problem on my own.
Apparently Git does not store source files in the centralised repository but only objects.

In order to import all source files I did the following on my PC

In eclipse File-> Import-> Git-> Project from Git
Then I selected Clone URI

I filled the location of the repository as follow

[image]

Eclipse retrieved successfully the master branch

[image]

Set the local destination of the new repository on my pc

[image]

And then I imported all sources accordingly as follow

[image]

Then I added the project to my working set

[image]

Hope this can be of help